# google spreadheets: what if values change when script is in execution?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a google script that reads values in a spreadsheet column to check if data match a regexp or if there are still some "Loading..." cells; if yes I do a sleep of some seconds and then I retry n times, waiting for loading data end. If after these retries not all data are present, then I return an error (other solutions are welcome :D ).
But my question now is:

I read the column with this instructions:

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);
  var dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName('data');
  var retVal = true;
  for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
    var lastRow = dataSheet.getLastRow();
    var values=dataSheet.getRange(1, colToCheck, lastRow, 1).getValues(); // here I skip title row
    for (var j=1; j<lastRow; j++) {
      ... do the check on the cell ...
      if (failed) {
        Utilities.sleep(5000);
        retVal = false;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (retVal) {
      break;
    }
  }
```

what if during this check, that may last several seconds, the sheet is updated with new data (i.e. new rows or changed values) ?
Are my `lastRow` and `values[]` updated or must I put also the `var dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName('data');` into the loop ? 
If I add rows during the debugging session, I don't see any change also if all instructions are put into the more external loop.
I hope I've been clear.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are invoking the method [`lastRow()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow) every time. So if new data is added and omitting propagation issues the value will be constantly changing.

If you don't what that to happen the solution is simple, just declare the variable `lastRow` outside the loop so you only are getting it one.

Also your code seems a little bit messy, what is the point of those for-inner loop, I thing there may be better ways to face your problem, but that would change too much the scope of the question. I would strongly recommend you to post another question if you would like to get help with that.

Comment: You are right. I put lastRow() inside the 1st loop of the 10 attempts just to have it always updated if the number of row changes, but maybe it's not a good idea.
I suppose it's not a good idea such kind of check to monitor if there are still cells with "Loading..." value in it.